# How to repalce "|" with "^" using regex_replace in Spark SQL, PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have to convert "|" to "^" with Spark.sql in PySpark, but it does not work as I expected.
Example:

```
dd=spark.sql("""select 'Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9' desc, 
regexp_replace('Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9','\\|','\\^') new_desc""")
dd.show(truncate=False)
```

It is showing:

```
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|desc                                      |desc_new                                                                             |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9|^Q^1^|^3^1^-^J^U^L^-^1^8^|^C^l^e^a^n^,^ ^Q^3^|^3^1^-^J^A^N^-^1^9^|^C^l^e^a^n^,^ ^Q^9^|
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Desired output would be:

```
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|desc                                      |desc_new                                                                             |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9 Q1^31-JUL-18^Clean, Q3^31-JAN-19^Clean, Q9|
+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I achieve my goal? I escaped using double back slash. Seems Spark.sql does not work. Please advise.

Comment: use triple back slash (another to escape the back slash)

Comment: Triple back slash... I will give it a try. Will update you, I don't have environment.

Comment: Comfirmed, triple back slashes work!  Thank you

Comment: Please post the answer. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to single escape the `|` for this, I think it is matching the null character because of the double escape so you are getting `^` between every character.

Try

```
dd=spark.sql("""select 'Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9' desc, 
regexp_replace('Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9','\|','^') new_desc""")
dd.show(truncate=False)
```

This should just replace any instance of `|` with `^` which I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I tried, did not work. Single slash is the same as double slash, I don't think Spark sql recognize the escape. I tried Hive, double slash works.

Answer (score 0):

Use triple backslash in `spark.sql()`.

```py
spark.sql("""
    select 'Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9' as desc, 
    regexp_replace('Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9','\\\|','^') as new_desc
    """). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
# |desc                                      |new_desc                                  |
# +------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
# |Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9|Q1^31-JUL-18^Clean, Q3^31-JAN-19^Clean, Q9|
# +------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

A single escape would work if you're using the dataframe API.

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9',)]).toDF(['desc']). \
    withColumn('new_desc', func.regexp_replace('desc', '\|', '^')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
# |desc                                      |new_desc                                  |
# +------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
# |Q1|31-JUL-18|Clean, Q3|31-JAN-19|Clean, Q9|Q1^31-JUL-18^Clean, Q3^31-JAN-19^Clean, Q9|
# +------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

*P.S. - `\` is a reserved character in `spark.sql()`.*